# How do you deal with a (unexpected indent) syntax in this particular program?

Tags: python, syntax, module, indentation, python-3.8

his is the error, when faced with running the program
any solutions to this problem will be appreciated

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xkohm.jpg

Comment: You have added the `python` tag, but you have added no code to your question.

Comment: Have you tried anything to fix this error?

Comment: Please prefer code : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 1):

You need to shift it one to the right, like this:

```
def openfile:
    try:
        stuff
    except:
        stuff
```

Thats what intendation error means, intendation is crucial in python.

Comment: Dear user, Thank you for helping me but unfortunately the code isn't working as it was attended too. I add more details on my program in the question

Comment: Write another comment when you are done, and copy the code instead of making a screenshot

Comment: Dear user, I have implemented your code and the program has no syntax errors although I appreciate you taking your own personal time to fix the error in my program  but the main purpose of the program is comprised.

the program needs to open a particular word file, which its unable too.

Comment: here is the code of my program

Comment: https://pastebin.com/DH7CNFei

Answer (score 1):

Use except **as** like this, you're missing the **as** plus it needs to be indented after the definition of a function.:

```
except Exception as e:
    #exception handling code
```

Comment: Thank you bro for the help

Comment: Dear user, I have implemented your code and the program has no syntax errors although I appreciate you taking your own personal time to fix the error in my program but the main purpose of the program is comprised. the program needs to open a particular word file, which its unable too. Here is the code of my program: https://pastebin.com/DH7CNFei